# Give an ordering to the set $\{ai\sqrt{7}\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I came across this problem in Protter's *A First Course in Real Analysis*, which asks:

> Consider the set of all numbers of the form $ai\sqrt{7}$ where $a$ is a real number and
> $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Show that it is possible to give this set an ordering in such a way that
> it satisfies **Axiom I**. Does this set form a field?

For context, the following is **Axiom I** stated in the book:

> **Axiom I** (Axiom of inequality). *Among all the numbers of the system, there is a set called the positive numbers which satisfies the conditions:* (i) *for any number $a$ exactly one of the three alternatives holds: $a$ is positive or $a=0$ or $-a$ is positive;* (ii) *any finite sum or product of positive numbers is positive.*

It seems that any number of the form $bi$ belongs to this set, since it could be converted to $(b/\sqrt{7})i\sqrt{7}$.

What confuses me is, the product of any two numbers in the set would not have imaginary part, so multiplication is not a closed operation, let alone designating a subset of positive numbers to satisfy the conditions.

I'm dubious about the validity of the problem, or do I misinterpret anything?

Comment: I completely agree with you. The set is not closed under multiplication (at least not usual complex multiplication). This answers the question "does this set form a field?" but it makes the question about Axiom I nonsensical or at least a bit hard to interpret.

Comment: One way to interpret the question about Axiom I is to rephrase (ii) in Axiom I as "Any finite sum of product of positive numbers *which is in the set* is positive." So in the case of $\{ai\sqrt 7, a \in \mathbb R\}$ this would mean that we only have to care about products of an odd number of elements.